# How to read platform properties for JUnits in Quarkus Application

Tags: java, junit, mocking, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I am writing JUnits for my Quarkus Application but getting below error on execution:

*Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: No config value of type [java.lang.String] exists for:*

Here it is looking for the properties mentioned in application.properties file.

This issue does not occur if I specify %test. as a prefix to the specific property. But this will pollute my existing application.properties file.

**is there any way I can move these properties to my test directory?**

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can have your test properties in the file `src/test/resources/application.properties`.
You don't need the `%test` prefix in this file.